# Tasker stops executing tasks after a certain period

Tags: tasker

For some reason I'm having problem with using Tasker on my Huawei Ascend P6:

- Android: 4.2.2
- My phone is running the official ROM (but rooted!)
- Run Foreground is checked under Menu / Prefs / Monitor /Run Foreground

I had set up a simple profile that would enable wifi, enable data, turn on auto sync, .. every X minutes. After trying this out it became clear that after a certain period Tasker would simply stop running this profile.
For testing purposes I have:

- Double checked that there are no task killers installed
- Created a
  profile of type "Time" that will Vibrate for 1 second from 07:00
  every 2m Till 22:30
- Enabled the "log to sdcard" functionality

After monitoring the log I have seen that there are no error but Tasker simply stops running the tasks after a certain period.

PS: I must say that I'm having the same issue with all other battery saving applications too (Juice Defender, GreenPower, Deep Sleep Battery Saver). They work perfectly until after a certain time they stop firing their events to enable the connection in the background.

**Edit1:** Below you can find a partial dump of the log that illustrates that it does actually run but that after a while it take way longer than configured.
As you can see at first it runs fine every 2 minutes while at some point it only runs every 10 minutes...

```
20130926 16.00.01 T Running  ID6      Test
20130926 16.00.01 P Instant  ID5      From 07:00 every 2m Till 22:30
20130926 16.00.01 A OK       ID6.1    Test.Vibrate
20130926 16.00.01 T ExitOK   ID6      Test
20130926 16.00.01 T Running  ID6:2    Test
20130926 16.00.01 A OK       ID6:2.1  Test.Vibrate
20130926 16.00.01 T ExitOK   ID6:2    Test
20130926 16.02.00 P Instant  ID5      From 07:00 every 2m Till 22:30
20130926 16.02.00 T Running  ID6      Test
20130926 16.02.00 A OK       ID6.1    Test.Vibrate
20130926 16.02.00 T ExitOK   ID6      Test
20130926 16.04.00 P Instant  ID5      From 07:00 every 2m Till 22:30
20130926 16.04.00 T Running  ID6      Test
20130926 16.04.00 A OK       ID6.1    Test.Vibrate
20130926 16.04.00 T ExitOK   ID6      Test
20130926 16.06.00 P Instant  ID5      From 07:00 every 2m Till 22:30
20130926 16.06.00 T Running  ID6      Test
20130926 16.06.00 A OK       ID6.1    Test.Vibrate
20130926 16.06.00 T ExitOK   ID6      Test
20130926 16.08.00 P Instant  ID5      From 07:00 every 2m Till 22:30
20130926 16.08.00 T Running  ID6      Test
20130926 16.08.00 A OK       ID6.1    Test.Vibrate
20130926 16.08.00 T ExitOK   ID6      Test
20130926 16.10.00 P Instant  ID5      From 07:00 every 2m Till 22:30
20130926 16.10.00 T Running  ID6      Test
20130926 16.10.00 A OK       ID6.1    Test.Vibrate
20130926 16.10.00 T ExitOK   ID6      Test
20130926 16.20.00 P Instant  ID5      From 07:00 every 2m Till 22:30
20130926 16.20.00 T Running  ID6      Test
20130926 16.20.00 A OK       ID6.1    Test.Vibrate
20130926 16.20.00 T ExitOK   ID6      Test
20130926 16.30.00 P Instant  ID5      From 07:00 every 2m Till 22:30
20130926 16.30.00 T Running  ID6      Test
20130926 16.30.00 A OK       ID6.1    Test.Vibrate
20130926 16.30.00 T ExitOK   ID6      Test
20130926 16.40.00 P Instant  ID5      From 07:00 every 2m Till 22:30
20130926 16.40.00 T Running  ID6      Test
20130926 16.40.00 A OK       ID6.1    Test.Vibrate
20130926 16.40.00 T ExitOK   ID6      Test
20130926 16.50.00 P Instant  ID5      From 07:00 every 2m Till 22:30
20130926 16.50.00 T Running  ID6      Test
20130926 16.50.00 A OK       ID6.1    Test.Vibrate
20130926 16.50.00 T ExitOK   ID6      Test
```

I also disabled the stock power manager using the below 2 methods to see if this might be causing the issue but it didn't not solve it:

1) Setting it to normal mode which results in the Power-manager doing no killing what-so-ever...

2) Removing the app (mv /system/app/hw-powermanager.apk /system/app/hw-powermanager.apk.backup) and rebooting the phone...

Any help?

Comment: Have anything in logcat that correlates with the slowdown and stop of Tasker? You mentioning that 'battery saver' apps show the same behavior make me think it's not a Tasker thing.

Comment: There is so much in the logcat... Don't really know how to filter out any messages that could be related to the problem.

Comment: I'd start first by lining up times. What's going on in logcat at the same second Tasker starts to slow? What about when Tasker stops for the last time? What about the exact second Tasker was supposed to start again? You can use [adb filter expressions](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#filteringOutput) and [alternative log buffers](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#alternativeBuffers) to try and narrow stuff down and cut through the clutter.

Comment: I have been logging and I didn't find anything suspicious.